# Using ImageMagick to scale a small size pdf to A4 with php

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

is there any one who can help me to solve my problem to scale a small pdf to A4 size with ImageMagick and php

i have tried all by best to do but not succeeded.

```
$imagick = new Imagick();

$imagick->setResolution(700,700);  

$imagick->readImage(realpath($upload_path.$akno.'.'.$extension));

$imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
$imagick->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
//$imagick->setImageResolution(300,300);
$imagick->scaleImage(1000,1000);
$imagick = $imagick->flattenImages();

//$imagick->adaptiveResizeImage(575,823);
//$imagick->setCompressionQuality(80);

$success = $imagick->writeImage($upload_path_u.$akno.'.jpg');
```

in the above code i tried changing to jpg if some one can provide a script to do for pdf thats is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "not succeeded" does it create the wrong result, fail with an error?

Comment: it create wrong image i.e similar to the source same dimensions

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
<?php
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(576,576);  
$imagick->readImage("a.pdf");
$imagick->resizeImage(2480,3508,Imagick::FILTER_CUBIC,1);
$imagick->setCompressionQuality(80);
$imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
$imagick->writeImage('result.jpg');
?>
```